# Object variable is undefined even though it's initialised

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node project where I create a Unit and an AddGate:

```
var Unit = function(value, weight) {
    this.value = value;
    this.weight = weight;
}

var AddGate = function() {
    this.sum_function = function(units) { 
        sum = 0;
        for (unit in units)
            sum += unit.value;
        return sum;
    };
};

AddGate.prototype = {
    forward: function(units) {
        this.units = units;
        this.output_unit = new Unit(this.sum_function(units), 0.0);
        return this.output_unit;
    }
}
```

I create some Units, an AddGate, and a ForwardNeuron (guess what I'm making):

```
var in_1 = new Unit(1.0, 0.0);
...
var in_9 = new Unit(3.0, 0.0);

var add = new AddGate();

var forwardNeuron = function() {
    a = add.forward({in_1, in_2, in_3, in_4, in_5, in_6, in_7, in_8, in_9});
};
forwardNeuron();
```

But for some reason, when in sum_function of AddGate, I can access each unit of units fine, but when I try to access unit.value, it says it's undefined, even though I've clearly initialised it. Am I missing something?

Comment: `for..in` loops are not for iterating values, they are for iterating keys of objects. Use `units[unit].value`.

Comment: Oh, that's because units is being treated like a map, isn't it?

Comment: It is not treated in any special way, it is just how `for...in` works.

Comment: I'm afraid I got a TypeError when I tried your response just now, @trincot.

Comment: @trincot On closer inspection, they're using an object, not an array for `units`.

Comment: Ah, yes, then `for of` wont work.

Comment: By the way you should use `const` or `let` or at least `var` when declaring variables such as with `sum = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments specify, `for (let unit in units)` will actually set `unit` as the *key* of the `units` object. You can correct this in a few ways such as using `units[unit].value`, but it would make more sense to me for the arguments to `forward` and `sum_function` to be an array. More or less as simple as:

```
add.forward([in_1, in_2, in_3, in_4, in_5, in_6, in_7, in_8, in_9]);
```

The sum would be a reduce operation on the array as in:

```
return units.reduce((sum, unit) => sum + unit.value, 0);
```

Comment: Good grief that's concise. This wins! Completely forgot about JS treating it as an object if you use curly braces. I'm used to Java.

Answer (score 0):

FYI 4castle's response worked for me - I wrote:

```
sum += units[unit].value;
```

That did the trick for me. Thanks again to 4castle and trincot for their speedy responses.

EDIT: The above is even better.